# Powershell commands suddenly stopped working

Tags: terminal, powershell, python

After I woke my pc up from sleep I tried running my Django server but nothing happens when I write the command. I get no error or feedback I just press enter and a new line appears. I've tried checking python --version in cmd but nothing happens there as well. I can cd into folders but no other commands work. I've restarted multiple times and also redownloaded vs code and python but nothing works

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer? Any issues that may have been caused by the computer being asleep should be resolved by a reboot.

Comment: @Worthwelle Yeah I've done it multiple times but it hasn't helped. I've left the pc on sleep multiple times with everything up and this hasn't happened before.

Comment: Then this doesn't sound like it's related to it being asleep. Did you change anything else recently? Install new software, run updates or change system configurations?

Comment: You said something like "_nothing happens when I write the command_". Can you please show us what kind of command you are writing and what it says?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/284#issuecomment-263687307) help at all?

Comment: @Worthwelle I worked on the app then I went to sleep and when I woke up and tried to work on it I noticed that nothing would run in the terminal. So I've done nothing recently. Nope didn't help since the issue doesn't seem to be tied to VS code or powershell since cmd doesn't work as well

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai commands that I've run before like "python manage.py runserver" or "python manage.py shell". It's the same with "python --version". I press enter and it's like nothing happened except I'm now on a new line waiting for a command and I can see the earlier one

Comment: It seems that the Command-Line PreProcessor System (the `Cmd.Exe` Executable Binary File, formerly known as the `Command.Com` Executable Binary File in the Olden Days of the _Microsoft_ _Disk-Operating System_) is messed up. Can you please attach a screenshot with it so that we can see how it is behaving?